# how to add custom column in SQL string query with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, default

I am using string query in sql and executing it with Execute method. I have to add an additional column with default value. that default value is contained in a variable. When i add that default valued column in the query string and execute it I get an error "Invalid column name 'dafaultValue' ".
Is there any other solution to do this ?
Here is my code:

```
Declare @variable Varchar(Max);
Declare @variableQuery Varchar(Max);
set @variable = 'Test';
set @variableQuery = 'select '+@variable+' as dest ,* from myTable ';

execute (@variableQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to contain the variable in single quotes:

```
set     @variableQuery = 'select '+ ''''+@variable+'''' +' as dest ,* from myTable';
```

Otherwise it thinks it is a column name in the table, which it isn't, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you @Leonidas. It worked. You have saved my hours. thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, when using dynamic SQL, a good tip is to replace EXECUTE with PRINT, so you can see what is going on, copy it and run it, helps see the error a little clearer.

Comment: Actually i did that. but i was using it for the first time so even after seeing it in print i could not found out the solution, although i got it that there is some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to learn to use `sp_executesql` and pass in parameters.  This is much safer than munging query strings:

```
Declare @variable Varchar(Max);
Declare @variableQuery Varchar(Max);
set @variable = 'Test';

set @variableQuery = 'select @variable as dest, t.* from myTable t';

exec sp_executesql @variableQuery,
                   N'@variable varchar(max)',
                   @variable = @variable;
```

This method also allows you to pass values back from the query, so for processing queries, it is more powerful than `exec`.

The query variable would often be declared to be `nvarchar()`, just to be as general as possible.

Comment: @variableQuery should be nvarchar